# Avoid random repeated results?

Tags: jquery, random

I'm trying to switch randomly some images within 4 divs, but I'm having trouble with repeated results.
In spite of having per example

1, 4, 2, 3
and then
4, 1, 3, 2

I'm getting

2, 2, 4, 2 and then 1, 3, 3 ,4

So I need to find a solution to avoid repeating numbers

this is the code

```
var tempo = setInterval(function() {
    $('.pub').each(function(i) {
        var imagens_pubs = ['img_1.jpg', 'img_2.jpg', 'img_3.jpg', 'img_4.jpg'];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagens_pubs.length);
        $(this).html('<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank"><img src="pubs/'+imagens_pubs[rand]+'" width="220px" height="50px"></img></a>');
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for each `.pub`, you're choosing a random item from the same array. The easiest way to do this would be to remove the element once you've chosen it, to stop repeated selections.

```
var tempo = setInterval(function() {
    var imagens_pubs = ['img_1.jpg', 'img_2.jpg', 'img_3.jpg', 'img_4.jpg'];

    $('.pub').each(function() {
        var rand = imagens_pubs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * imagens_pubs.length), 1)[0]; // Chose a random element and remove it. See the documentation for Array.splice.

        $(this).html('<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank"><img src="pubs/' + rand + '" width="220px" height="50px"></img></a>');
    });
}, 5000);​
```

Note we've moved the declaration of `imagens_pub` out of the `each()`, otherwise the array will be re-declared for each `.pub`.

You can see this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/3xcKb/

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at how to generate a random permutation of an array. The [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) algorithm is very simple and easy to implement:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```